# More Time taking While retriving data from the ListView in c#

Tags: c#

Consider the ListView item Having two columns with more than 35,000 rows inserted already. Now the user selects the any 30,000 rows from the ListView. I want all the Selected Items data let's Say (Item,Subitems)

Here is my code.

**ListView Name** : lstViewData

```
        List<string> l_lstData = new List<String>();
        for(int l_nItem =0;l_nItem<lstViewData.SelectedItems.Count;l_nItem++)
        {
          l_lstData.Add(lstViewData.SelectedItems[l_nItem].Text+              
          lstViewData.SelectedItems[l_nItem].SubItems[1].Text);
        }
```

It Will take more than Half an hour in my PC(Configuration - IntelCore2Duo @2.40GHZ).Since the no. of selected items is morethan 30,000 in ListView

Kindly tell me the solution If any one knows?

Comment: Can you tell me the procedure to page the data

Comment: How do they select the items? One at a time or hundreds at a time??

Comment: example : they select 30,000 rows at a time

Comment: I was thinking that if they select them one at a time you can add them as they select them, instead of all at the end which would make it a great deal quicker, but as it stands I dont see anything you can do to make it a great deal quicker, its just too many rows

Comment: I cant get you what you are coming to say

Answer (score 0):

You are using the + operator:

```
l_lstData.Add(lstViewData.SelectedItems[l_nItem].Text+lstViewData.SelectedItems[l_nItem].SubItems[1].Text);
```

you should NEVER in a case where there is a lot of operations use the + operator on strings, as they are immutable. You should use a `StringBuilder`.

```
l_lstData.Add(sbuilder.Append(lstViewData.Seleteditems[l_nItem].Text).Append(lstViewData.SelectedItems[l_nItem].SubItems[1].Text).ToString());
sbuilder.Remove(0, sbuilder.Length);
```

where `sbuilder` is an instance of `StringBuilder`

Comment: @RichardJ.Ross : The problem is still exists eventhough i changed the string instance to StringBuilder . It is due to retriving the data from the ListView

Comment: That doesn't make sense, as listviews are meant to be really fast for their getting and setting. Were you allocating an instance of `StringBuilder` every time? if so, then just reuse the same `StringBuilder`, and don't reallocate it. Also, there was a bug in my code, and I edited it.

Comment: @Richard : No ,I did n't reinitialise the stringBuilder instance inside the for Loop.I initialises it before the Loop.Still it will take more than 30 Minutes

Comment: Try disabling vshosting, as that will make it faster, and make sure that the JIT is optimizing your code. I have another answer, but i'm not sure if it will work, depending upon the rest of your project.

Comment: I would have to see more of your code to answer your question accurately.

Comment: can you do it in a simple windows application and let me know the time taken in your side?

Comment: OK no problem and ill comment here when I complete

Comment: I will get the Solution.Now i am using LINQ.Here is my Code.

Comment: List<String> l_lstListViewItem = new List<string>();
                    l_lstListViewItem = (from ListViewItem iItem in lstVPattrnComb.SelectedItems
                                         select (iItem.Text + iItem.SubItems[1].Text)).ToList();

Comment: I figured out the problem btw...You are probably putting the code shown above in the selectedIndexChanged Method, and that is called repeatedly after you select items, so say you select 100 items, it is called 100 times! you need to put the code int the double click event, not the selected index changed. And it took 240 milliseconds on my virtual machine PC.